# deserialization xml string as string element c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, object, serialization

i have a xml string like this:

```
<root>
    <header>
        <reqType>REQUEST</reqType>
        <priority>1</priority>
        <channel>TTP</channel>
        <synasyn>true</synasyn>
        <zip>false</zip>
    </header>
    <body>
        <command>getCustInfo</command>
        <customerID>14231131</customerID>
    </body>
</root>
```

And my code bellow

```
[XmlRoot ("root")]
public class root
{
    public header header;
    [XmlElement("body")]
    public string body;
}
[XmlRoot("header")]
public class header
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public string reqType;
    .....
}
```

when i deserialization xml string above:
  `root data = CompressHelper.fromXML<root>(xml);`
 i got a resut "body" elements is "getCustInfo"
 So the question is how can i deserialization to get result "body" as a string value:

```
<command>getCustInfo</command>
<customerID>14231131</customerID>
```

Comment: <root>
 <header>
  <reqType>REQUEST</reqType>
  <priority>1</priority>
  <channel>TTP</channel>
  <synasyn>true</synasyn>
  <zip>false</zip>
 </header>
 <body>
  <command>getCustInfo</command>
  <customerID>14231131</customerID>
 </body>
</root>

Comment: Sorry, i updated

Comment: Could you please share expected result with sample?

Comment: Change FROM : public string body; To : public body body;  And then create a class body.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization will target text of individual elements only. You are better off using Xpath to get the text of xml tag you want. Below is how you can do it

```
 string xml = @"<root>
                   <header>
                       <reqType>REQUEST</reqType>
                       <priority>1</priority>
                       <channel>TTP</channel>
                       <synasyn>true</synasyn>
                       <zip>false</zip>
                   </header>
                   <body>
                       <command>getCustInfo</command>
                       <customerID>14231131</customerID>
                   </body>
                </root>";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode body = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/body");
string bodyInnerXML = body.InnerXml;
```